# How to make a bot know how to delete webhooks that it made and by channel mentions

Tags: javascript, discord.js, commando

Hi I want to make a Discord.JS-Commando command where if you select a channel, the bot removes a webhook it owns there and if it's named `Marker` and if it detects if there's no webhook there that it owns named `Marker` it just `return message.channel.send("Hey! There's no webhook I own in this channel!")`

The bot deletes a webhook even though it didn't make it, and it's not in the channel I mention. How do I fix this?

Searching it up on Google, there was nothing.
There wasn't anything on deleting webhooks except discord.js docs.

```
const hooks1 = await message.guild.fetchWebhooks();
await hooks1.forEach(async webhook => {
    if (!watchChannel.id == webhook.channelID) return
    if (!webhook.owner.id == `595840576386236437`) return
    if (!webhook.name == `Marker`) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, Nothing was found. You or someone else may have renamed the webhook. Please delete the webhook manually. Sorry for the inconvenience`);
    else
message.channel.send(`Deleted successfully.`).then(msg => {message.delete(4000)}).catch(error => console.log(error))
webhook.delete(`Requested per ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`);
});
```

I expect the bot to know how to delete the webhook that it made, in a mentioned channel, but the bot doesn't know what webhook to delete.

Comment: First, a little advice: use `===` instead of `==` (you can see the difference [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons/359509#359509) and add bracket for your `if`. Yes one line `if` doesn't need them, however it's easier to read and way better if you need to edit your code (example, you want to add a `console.log`? If you put it like this, the second statement won't be in the if. You'll have to add the bracket, but you can forget, leading to wrong debugging or behaviour in your code)

Comment: Do you have an error? Are you sure the webhook exist? Are you sure the owner is the good id? Did you try to log `webhook`?

Comment: 1. Error in Discord: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined, 2. Yes, it is named "Marker" and owned by 595840576386236437. 3. I made sure the bot's ID and the owner.ID matched. 4. Not yet.

Comment: Anyways, I got the answer to just put it as `webhook.delete()` and now the problem is that it deletes all webhooks it sees, even if I make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```js
> if (!watchChannel.id == webhook.channelID) return
> if (!webhook.owner.id == `595840576386236437`) return
> if (!webhook.name == `Marker`) return
> ```

None of these lines are working as you expect them to.

```js
const id = '189855563893571595';

console.log(id === '189855563893571595');

console.log(id !== '1234');  // id is not equal to '1234': true
console.log(!id === '1234'); // false is equal to '1234' : false
```

---

`!` acts as the **logical NOT** operator.

> Returns `false` if its single operand can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns `true`.

<sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators</sup>

`!watchChannel.id` is a [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean); it will never equal `webhook.channelID` unless the latter is `false`. The same goes for all three conditions in your code. Therefore, your bot is deleting Webhooks that aren't its own because the `if` statements are not true when you expected them to be.

---

`!==` is known as the **non-identity/strict inequality** operator.

> ...[R]eturns `true` if the operands are not equal and/or not of the same type.

<sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators</sup>

This (or the inequality operator `!=` to go along with the twins) is the operator your want to be using. It will correctly compare the properties.

---

Improving your current code, we can...

- Fetch the Webhooks only from the specified channel.
- Filter the [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) before looping through.
- Use a modern [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop which will work correctly with asynchronous code.
- Make sure to catch *all* rejected promises.
- Get into the habit of using the identity operator `===` instead of the equality operator `==`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509) for reasoning.

```js
const webhooks = await watchChannel.fetchWebhooks();
const myWebhooks = webhooks.filter(webhook => webhook.owner.id === client.user.id && webhook.name === 'Marker');

try {
  if (myWebhooks.size === 0) return await message.channel.send('I don\'t own any Webhooks there...');

  for (let [id, webhook] of myWebhooks) await webhook.delete(`Requested by ${message.author.tag}`);

  await message.channel.send('Successfully deleted all of my Webhooks from that channel.');
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);

  await message.channel.send('Something went wrong.')
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the discord.js documentation? It provides everything that you need to know, such as things like objects, classes, methods/properties for the objects and classes, stuff like that. Anyway, I think the problem is that when you try to delete the webhook you are using `webhook.delete` but when you use `delete` without the parentheses means that you are trying to access the property `delete`, not the method. The correct way to do it would be to call `webhook.delete();` as this calls the `delete()` method from the `Webhook` class.

It's right here on the docs:

Webhook class: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Webhook

Delete method: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Webhook?scrollTo=delete